# Adding Highcharts chart to JasperReport template generated with Java API

Tags: java, jasper-reports

We're evaluating the pro version of JasperReports. For a POC, we need to generate dynamically (with the Java API) a report template based on columns selected by a user on the UI, including a total at the bottom of the report. We are using the `net.sf.jasperreports.*` library to generate a report template, compile it and run it. That works fine.

However we want to add, next to the total, a chart with each of the values that comprise the total. We found the `jaspersoft/highcharts` jar and that seems to be the one to use, but need a code snippet to know how to add a chart (`JRDesign` chart element) to a report band (`JRBand`).

Any insights will be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**
Reference on Jaspersoft Pro support of Highcharts [here](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/using-functions-html5-charts-highcharts)

Comment: Hi @ps0604, You have used highcharts tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about `jasper-reports` library. I can suggest you to add a question directly on: https://community.jaspersoft.com/answers

Comment: I agree, the problem is related to jasper-reports, not highcharts. I removed the tag.

Comment: If you're using the pro version then I think it's faster and formal to contact their technical support

Comment: We're not using the pro version, we're evaluating it. The reason I posted the question in SO is that Jaspersoft doesn't offer support in evaluations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a chart element via the Java API consists of creating a `JRDesignComponentElement` object which wraps a `com.jaspersoft.jasperreports.highcharts.charts.StandardChartComponent` instance, which contains all the chart configuration.

Here's some sample code that creates a report that contains a chart in the summary section.  The report can be run using an empty data source with one or more data records.

You'll of course need to adapt the code to populate the chart with the data that you want to display.  You'd mainly need to change the level bucket expression and the measure value expression.

To compile the code you'll need to a jasperreports-highcharts jar in the classpath (plus dependencies - jasperreports-pro, jasperreports-license and others).

```
JasperDesign report = new JasperDesign();
report.setName("chart");

JRDesignBand summary = new JRDesignBand();
summary.setHeight(300);
report.setSummary(summary);

JRDesignComponentElement chartElement = new JRDesignComponentElement();
chartElement.setX(0);
chartElement.setY(0);
chartElement.setWidth(500);
chartElement.setHeight(300);
chartElement.setComponentKey(HighchartsConstants.DEFAULT_COMPONENT_KEY);

StandardChartComponent chart = new StandardChartComponent();
chart.setType(ChartType.COLUMN_CHART);

StandardChartSetting defaultSetting = new StandardChartSetting();
defaultSetting.setName(HighchartsConstants.SETTING_NAME_DEFAULT);
//set a static String property
defaultSetting.addChartProperty(new StandardChartProperty("title.text", 
        "My chart title", null));
//set an expression based boolean property
defaultSetting.addChartProperty(new StandardChartProperty("plotOptions.series.dataLabels.enabled", 
        null, new JRDesignExpression("true")));
chart.addChartSetting(defaultSetting);

DesignMultiAxisData data = new DesignMultiAxisData();
DesignMultiAxisDataset dataset = new DesignMultiAxisDataset();
//this actually means feeding data to the chart on each record
dataset.setIncrementType(IncrementTypeEnum.NONE);
data.setDataset(dataset);

DesignDataAxis rowAxis = new DesignDataAxis();
rowAxis.setAxis(Axis.ROWS);
DesignDataAxisLevel level = new DesignDataAxisLevel();
level.setName("rows");
level.setLabelExpression(new JRDesignExpression("\"Rows\""));
DesignDataLevelBucket levelBucket = new DesignDataLevelBucket();
//expression that produces category values
levelBucket.setExpression(new JRDesignExpression("\"Row \" + $V{REPORT_COUNT}"));
level.setBucket(levelBucket);
rowAxis.addLevel(level);
data.addDataAxis(rowAxis);

DesignDataMeasure measure = new DesignDataMeasure();
measure.setName("measure");
measure.setLabelExpression(new JRDesignExpression("\"Data\""));
measure.setCalculation(CalculationEnum.NOTHING);
measure.setValueClassName("java.lang.Integer");
//expression that produces series values
measure.setValueExpression(new JRDesignExpression("$V{REPORT_COUNT}"));
data.addMeasure(measure);

chart.setMultiAxisData(data);

chartElement.setComponent(chart);
summary.addElement(chartElement);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for